# What is extension of scalars used for in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Given a ring homomorphism $f:A \rightarrow B$ and an $A$-module $M$, one can construct and $A$-module with the tensor product: $M_B=B \otimes_A M$ which has a $B$-module structure. This is said to be obtained from M by extension of scalars.

This construction is shown in many commutative algebra textbooks, but I fail to see its importance in algebraic geometry, as I haven't seen it mentioned in any algebraic geometry textbook or notes.

Could you give me any examples of this construction being useful in algebraic geometry?

Comment: For instance, you can go from an algebraic variety with points in a field $k$ to points in the algebraic closure of $k$. Many results are valid only for algebraically closed fields.

Comment: Interesting, but how is this useful for studying properties of the original variety? How do you return afterwards?

Comment: Some properties can be proved with *faithfully flat descent*, for example: you prove it for algebraically closed fields, then ‘descend’ it to the base field.

Comment: For example, sometimes you want to know about the dimensions of certain cohomology groups, and these do not change if you extend the base field. All of a sudden you've given yourself a lot more room to make geometric arguments.